# Apply function to 2D Numpy array to create new, reduced array

Tags: python, numpy, transform

I am trying to apply a transform to a numpy 2D array, and my code seems overly complex (a lot of transposing for example).

Especially this line, where I am simply trying to extract a single column from the array, but as a 2D, not 1D series:

```
r1 = arrInput[:,n].reshape(arrInput.shape[0],1)
```

The resulting array is one column narrower than the input. The code works, but I feel I am missing a level of understanding of numpy.

The complete code:

```
import numpy as np

def fwdZeroRate(shtTenor,shtRate,lngTenor,lngRate):
    return 100 * (pow(pow(1 + (lngRate/100),lngTenor) / pow(1 + (shtRate/100),shtTenor),1/(lngTenor-shtTenor))-1)

arrInput = np.array( [[2.170,1.905,1.850,2.031 ],
                      [2.203,1.938,1.866,2.030 ],
                      [2.367,2.038,1.936,2.070 ],
                      [2.315,1.990,1.900,2.045 ],
                      [2.291,1.941,1.871,2.040 ],
                      [2.302,1.952,1.881,2.0525]])

tenors = [2,5,10,30]

res=[]

for n in range(len(tenors)-1):
    t1 = tenors[n]
    t2 = tenors[n+1]

    r1 = arrInput[:,n].reshape(arrInput.shape[0],1)
    r2 = arrInput[:,n+1].reshape(arrInput.shape[0],1)
    
    arr = fwdZeroRate(t1,r1,t2,r2).T[0]
    res.append(arr) 

arrResult = np.array(res).T
print(arrResult)
```

with output:

```
[[1.7287153  1.79502968 2.12162059]
 [1.76171517 1.79405085 2.11209899]
 [1.81925431 1.83410196 2.13706604]
 [1.77390706 1.81007942 2.11757736]
 [1.70833223 1.80104807 2.12460511]
 [1.71933216 1.81004944 2.13835823]]
```

I'd be grateful for more pythonic solutions to the task!

Comment: When subscripting a Numpy array, you can include `None` as one of the dimensions.  This says to add a extra dimension of size 1 where it didn't exist before.  So it sounds like you want `arrInput[:,n,None]`.   You can also write `np.newaxis` if you want to make your intent clearer, but that just evaluates to `None`.

Comment: @FrankYellin Thanks! That's just the sort of insight I was after.

Comment: `arrInput[:,[n]]` - index with a list rather than a scalar.  Or `arrInput[:,n:n+1]` or a slice.